# Sum a unique query on multiple pages in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, uniqueidentifier

This is a tough one!

Sheet I'm working on: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fIBFq4q179k6-5YuhoFZ-3X84tMMkLmIUeV9-KpjN9I/edit?usp=sharing

On the 'Report' Tab, in cell C22 and D22 I am trying to figure out how to Total the amount that was paid in the months of November and October. Across all tabs (and to include future tabs as they are added).

You can see on the individual stock number pages (Example 'PT-1010!' K14:K) that the payments are already broken down by total for the month. How do I search across all pages, find out if it says 'November-20' and count them all up - and spit out one number?

My brain hurts lol - any help is very much appreciated!!

Comment: So you basically want to look accross all sheets for those cells that are ```November-20``` and add up the value which is next to these cells right (amount paid)?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I may have an answer below but am waiting for me to get access to his test page so I can really dive into that formula. Do you know of an easier way to pull that info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help.  ([See my sample sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H4L81rce5UskACBHOy7IWv1V_3g29xoyO2MiD_a1qmM/edit?usp=sharing))

[image]

This grabs an array of all of the payments, with a date less than now, using indirect addressing from a list of the stock numbers from the Customers page.  I pull this list into a location (U2 in my testing) using this formula:

```
=query(Customers!A5:A,"where A<>'' order by A",0)
```

So that is always a current/dynamic list.

Then the main formula uses indirect addressing to pull the tab names from this list, and collects all of the data.  I added the filters to reduce the number of rows collected, since you have lots of future dates.

Then I use a query to filter by the desired month, using indirect addressing to the date cells in Report.  This allows the exact same formula to be used for both C22 (Nov.) and D22 (Oct.).

The main formula, calculating the totals paid in each month, is:

```
=query({filter(indirect(U3 &"!B7:E"),indirect(U3 &"!B7:B")<Now());
  filter(indirect(U4 &"!B7:E"),indirect(U4 &"!B7:B")<Now());
  filter(indirect(U5 &"!B7:E"),indirect(U5 &"!B7:B")<Now());
  filter(indirect(U6 &"!B7:E"),indirect(U6 &"!B7:B")<Now());
  filter(indirect(U7 &"!B7:E"),indirect(U7 &"!B7:B")<Now());
  filter(indirect(U8 &"!B7:E"),indirect(U8 &"!B7:B")<Now());
  filter(indirect(U9 &"!B7:E"),indirect(U9 &"!B7:B")<Now());
  filter(indirect(U10 &"!B7:E"),indirect(U10 &"!B7:B")<Now());
  filter(indirect(U11 &"!B7:E"),indirect(U11 &"!B7:B")<Now());
  filter(indirect(U12 &"!B7:E"),indirect(U12 &"!B7:B")<Now());
  filter(indirect(U13 &"!B7:E"),indirect(U13 &"!B7:B")<Now());
  filter(indirect(U14 &"!B7:E"),indirect(U14 &"!B7:B")<Now());
  filter(indirect(U15 &"!B7:E"),indirect(U15 &"!B7:B")<Now());
  filter(indirect(U16 &"!B7:E"),indirect(U16 &"!B7:B")<Now());
  filter(indirect(U17 &"!B7:E"),indirect(U17 &"!B7:B")<Now());
  filter(indirect(U18 &"!B7:E"),indirect(U18 &"!B7:B")<Now());
  filter(indirect(U19 &"!B7:E"),indirect(U19 &"!B7:B")<Now())  },
  "select sum(Col4) where Col4 >0 and Col1 >= date '"& text(indirect(address(row()-3,column()  ,4,1)),"yyyy-mm-dd") &"' 
                                  and Col1 <  date '"& text(indirect(address(row()-3,column()-1,4,1)),"yyyy-mm-dd") &"' label sum(Col4) '' ",0)
```

Using just formulae, instead of a script, I can't think of another way to cycle through multiple tabs.  You could repeat the FILTER lines in the formula to handle as many customers as you need.  If you are going to have a lot more, then you might need to go to a script.  You might need dummy tabs, if you extend the formula now, to handle future customers.

And, I think some error checking may be required, to handle possible errors in the indirect addressing to tabs.  Possibly a test to ensure we aren't pulling a blank value from the list of stock numbers, which equate to the tab names.  Or maybe an IFERROR can cover those, one for each FILTER statement.

Let me know if this helps.

If you remove the date criteria in the last rows, and change the "sum(Col4)" to "Col1, Col4 order by Col1", you get all the data records with payments (column E in each tab, correct?) and can verify the result.

Comment: What an amazing answer! For some reason I couldn't get my head around it until I dove into your explanation and breakdown for each step of the process. I ended up adding a dummy tab for the Stock Numbers (to keep the report page nice), then adjusted the formula to pull from that page. It WORKED!! Thank you very very much! Huge help!

Comment: Glad it helped.  I just gave you access, but I assumed you'd take a copy, to be able to really play with it.  Let me know if you have any questions.  If I can figure out the best error checking to add to the formula, I'll post it here